# EEvEE doesn't render every frames animation

Tags: rendering, animation, eevee-render-engine

Problem to render every frames in animation in eevee

*There is a problem that eevee doesn't render every frames and make mistakes.
explain: I want to render a plane that shows a video (includes 3 frames and it repeats). in view mode when i play animation every thing works well , but when I start rendering frames eevee doesn't render every 3 frames and Exactly it render frame 1, frame 2, frame 2 (instead of frame 3).
 here is a VERY SHORT video to explain problem. Thankkss*

[VERY SHORT video](https://dev-files.blender.org/file/data/2qgo6mxfjovass6fg47w/PHID-FILE-56zhi4iehgdwgzjo52gx/EEVEE_bug.mp4)

Comment: This is a link only question. If the link goes down, the question doesn't make sense. Can you please edit the question and include the information from the video.

Comment: @Leander Hi. i changed it. but I think I couldn't express the problem using letters in Compared with the Short video :)